# how write iphone apps using objective-c from terminal

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i would like to know how to develop iphone apps for terminal just like we do for android

by using the

android --target 1 --name someApp --package --com.someApp --activity main

command

how to do this for iphone apps

it should be like

iphone // then some options

or what is xcode or someother ide doing behind the scene ..??

Comment: Xcode is a tool which is used to develop applications for iOS and also for Mac. It provides many facilities like debugging,memory management, clean code writing, etc.

Comment: Trust me ;) you don't want to do that ;)

Comment: **Terminal** why friend? Has anyone challenged you to do this? This is as difficult as swimming Amazon from start to end point

Comment: Mr. Vaidya is indeed correct, you do not want to do that!

Comment: every one you are correct i just want to know how or is that possible i never said i want to do that..

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "How do I develop from the terminal?", then, please, don't go there, but if you do:

The xcode project files are xml, they contain all information about your project, compile instructions, source files, resources, etc. You could create and manipulate these and use xcodebuild to compile your project.

If your question is 'How do I compile apps from the terminal?', then there are some valid reasons for doing so, automations, testing, etc. When you have installed Xcode, there are also some command line tools available, like xcodebuild. You can use these tools to build from the command line:

[xcodebuild command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

Take a look at the xcoder ruby gem:

https://github.com/rayh/xcoder

Comment: yes i beleive my question is clear it is "how do i develop from terminal" trust me i just want to know how to do it,,so pls help me by directly answering it and just dont say dont go there ,,i just want to know how to do it.just think of it like this i want to build my own ide how to do it??